# "virtual" sites in the navigation tree

Tags: sitecore-api

When I have have my navigation tree with page X and page Y and some content on page X and I need to show the same page X with the same content under an other content tree. E.g. page X under page Z.

Is it possible to only create a "virtual" Link or so? So that I have the same page and I need to nurse the content once?

**Solution:** [Cloneing in sitecore](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/content%20authoring/managing%20items/cloning%20%20versioning/clones)

Comment: Item clones. But you really should be building your navigation tree exactly as you describe it. As a navigation tree - not a bastardised extract of your content hierarchy structure.

Comment: @MarkCassidy Yes I know but sometimes its really hard to decide if you want to create a complete second structure for your navigation or to clone some items so that its working linke intended. I am just evaluating the possibilities

Comment: It's not hard to decide at all :-)    You going to fill in a self answer here, or should I scrap the post? :-)

Comment: You may also use a droplink field and then point to the page you want

Comment: @HishaamNamooya do I have to program here something for this solution or does it work out of the box?